# Poisson integral for the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question, and I think I am close but cannot see the last steps:

Show that:

$$
P_r(\gamma) = \frac {1 - r^2} {1 - 2r\cos\gamma + r^2} = \Re \left( \frac{t+z}{t-z} \right).
$$

Where $z= re^{i \phi}$ and $t = e^{i \theta}$.

I already used diverse literature, but in most books, it is written as a statement. But no proof.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: How is $\gamma$ introduced? It is not in the definitions of $t$ and $z$?

Comment: My fault: gamma has to be (theta - phi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

With ${\bf Re}\,w=\dfrac12(w+\bar{w})$ from RHS:
$${\bf Re}\dfrac{t+z}{t-z}=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{t+z}{t-z}+\dfrac{\bar{t}+\bar{z}}{\bar{t}-\bar{z}}\right)=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{2|t|^2-2|z|^2}{(t-z)(\bar{t}-\bar{z})}\right)=\dfrac{|t|^2-|z|^2}{|t|^2+|z|^2-2{\bf Re}(t\bar{z})}$$

Comment: So we don't have to use the "values" for z and t? But why can we say that this is a "result" from the LHS?

Comment: After you do this simplifying you should substitute the value of $t$ and $z$ for finding the LHS.

Comment: Can you help me with the 'simplifying'? After 1.5 hours it is even getting worse instead of simple :-). I even used maple-17. Perhaps I forget a 'trick' somewhere.

Comment: What is $|t|$.?

Comment: I guess 1, but using the general definition of a complex number: t= a + bi, so |t| = Sqrt(a^2 + b^2), which must be 1. But what about |z| is it r?

Comment: use complex number $z=re^{i\phi}=r\cos\phi+ir\sin\phi$.

Comment: Agree, I see what the numerator becomes and denominator. LHS and RHS becomes equal.

Comment: Avoiding the Theta and Phi, I will use x and y. For the last part: t= cos x + i sin x, z(conjugate) = r( cos y - i sin y). If we multiply these we obtain for the real part: r*cos x * cos y + r * sin x * sin y. And now using the doubling formula for this?

Comment: $t\bar{z}=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)(r\cos\phi-ir\sin\phi)=(r\cos\phi\cos\theta+r\sin\theta\sin\phi)+i(-r\sin\phi\cos\theta+r\cos\phi\sin\theta)=r\cos(\theta-\phi)+ir\cos(\theta-\phi)$

Comment: With exponential $$t\bar{z}=e^{i\theta}re^{-i\phi}=re^{i(\theta-\phi)}$$ then ${\bf Re}\,(t\bar{z})=r\cos(\theta-\phi)$.